# Windows Phone 7 : Socket Programming

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7

Is there any support for TCP/IP Sockets in Windows Phone 7? I'm not having any luck finding it so far.
I want to connect to a port on a server and issue commands/receive responses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was added in mango version.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=VS.96).aspx

Answer (score 5):

from the WM Phone 7 Dev FAQ:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/2892a6f0-ab26-48d6-b63c-e38f62eda3b3

Can I use Sockets for peer to peer communication?

Windows Phone 7 Series currently does not expose the Socket classes.  While the version of Silverlight on the phone follows closely the feature list for Silverlight 3 on the desktop, it is a subset of those features and will not contain all classes.  (It also holds a superset of classes not available in Silverlight 3.)

Comment: Boo! Oh well, looks like I'm going to have to find an alternative, at least the "currently" gives me hope!

Comment: Currently in WP7.5(Mango) there are sockets. SO the answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 3):

According to microsoft announcment, sockets will be available in next "mango" update for late 2011. Dev tools to ship May 2011.
["...The integration extends deeper into the operating system via sockets..."](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/04/13/be-what-s-next-with-mango-developer-tools-and-platform.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

While sockets are not exposed in Windows Phone 7, the better alternative would be to use WCF.

Comment: Can you use WCF to call an arbitrary JSON service?