# Opening a TCP connection in Windows Phone 7

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, tcp

As the current version of the SDK [doesn't support Socket class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509780/windows-phone-7-socket-programming).

Is is possible to open a TCP connection?

I cannot see the point of using WCF to make a typical client/server scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but updating this for the sake of those that come and read this later. In the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK (which is for the version 7.5 OS) TCP and UDP sockets are supported.

Answer (score 0):

WCF with Windows Phone 7 is done by way of basicHttpBinding.

Comment: So, no TCP connection allowed with this method :(

Comment: This is the current state of things for the v1 release. Is it onerous to support an additional binding for existing WCF services using other types of bindings?